# Named blocks in Ember

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a way to have "named blocks"? For example,

```
{{#namedBlock "reusableBlock"}}
  {{!-- block with a lot of properties and stuff that will look ugly if you hardcode in multiple places --}}
{{/namedBlock}}
```

And somewhere else in the code,

```
{{#if someCondition}}
  <div class="wrapper">
    {{reusableBlock}}
  </div>
{{else}}
  {{reusableBlock}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Just create a component for it

Comment: Isn't there another way? Let's say that the block itself is a component that needs a lot of properties to be passed and has block content. Even if I create a wrapping component, it won't look neat.

Comment: There used to be a thing called partials. They are deprecated.

Comment: You may be able to reduce the ugliness with a creative use of the `let` helper. See https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/helper-functions/#toc_the-let-helper

Comment: If you post the ugly code, I can help you with that

Comment: Just to be sure: You aren't talking about [Yieldable Named Blocks](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0460-yieldable-named-blocks.md), are you?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for components. [Named blocks](https://github.com/ember-polyfills/ember-named-blocks-polyfill#readme) are a different thing.

Create a component in [Ember CLI](https://ember-cli.com/) by entering `ember g component my-component` into the terminal. Or create your `.hbs` file manually in the `app/components` folder. Then add some code.

```
{{! my-component.hbs }}
<div class="my-component">
   {{! Your code goes here }}
</div>
```

Then in another template, call that component.

```
{{! about-page.hbs }}
<h1>This is the about page</h1>
<MyComponent />
```